# Rrule - reading 'freq', 'interval', etc values?

Tags: python, python-dateutil, rrule

How to **extract 'freq', 'interval', etc values from Rrule**

```
from dateutil.rrule import *

my_rrule = rrule(freq=DAILY, interval=2, count=3)
print(str(my_rrule))
print(my_rrule.count())
print(my_rrule.interval())
```

```
>>>
DTSTART:20190130T025306
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2;COUNT=3
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/test2.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(my_rrule.interval())
AttributeError: 'rrule' object has no attribute 'interval'
>>>
```

This method reads the 'count' attribute value but breaks for 'interval' , 'freq' etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change code

```
print(my_rrule.interval())
```

to

```
print(my_rrule._interval)
```

You can get a clue from the init function of rrule, it store interval as _interval in the class, which means you'd better not try to use this variable from outside because that the instance may have a side-effect of using this variable by changing its value or its logic depends on it.

```
def __init__(self, freq, dtstart=None,
             interval=1, wkst=None, count=None, until=None, bysetpos=None,
             bymonth=None, bymonthday=None, byyearday=None, byeaster=None,
             byweekno=None, byweekday=None,
             byhour=None, byminute=None, bysecond=None,
             cache=False):
    super(rrule, self).__init__(cache)
    global easter
    if not dtstart:
        if until and until.tzinfo:
            dtstart = datetime.datetime.now(tz=until.tzinfo).replace(microsecond=0)
        else:           
            dtstart = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
    elif not isinstance(dtstart, datetime.datetime):
        dtstart = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(dtstart.toordinal())
    else:
        dtstart = dtstart.replace(microsecond=0)
    self._dtstart = dtstart
    self._tzinfo = dtstart.tzinfo
    self._freq = freq
    self._interval = interval
    self._count = count
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks for the explanation

(Just a note for others ... '_freq' will return a corresponding integer , ie DAILY=3)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it (in recurrent for format()):

```
    def parse_rrule(r):
        """Sample:
        DTSTART:19970930T090000
        RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;COUNT=10;BYMONTHDAY=1,-1
        EXDATE:19960402T010000,19960403T010000,19960404T010000
        """
        r = str(r)      # If it's an rrule, convert to the string representation
        result = {}
        elements = r.split('\n')
        for element in elements:
            if ':' in element:
                name, values = element.split(':')
            else:
                name = element
                values = ''

            vls = {}
            for value in values.split(';'):
                if '=' in value:
                    k, v = value.split('=')
                    v = todatetime(toint(v))
                    if isinstance(v, str) and ',' in v:
                        l = []
                        for e in v.split(','):
                            e = todatetime(toint(e))
                            l.append(e)
                        v = l
                    vls[k] = v
                else:
                    vls[value] = None
            if len(vls) == 1 and list(vls.values())[0] is None:
                vls = list(vls.keys())[0]
                if isinstance(vls, str) and ',' in vls:
                    l = []
                    for e in vls.split(','):
                        e = todatetime(toint(e))
                        l.append(e)
                    vls = l
                else:
                    vls = todatetime(toint(vls))
            result[name] = vls
        log.debug(f'parse_rrule({r}) = {result}')
        return result
```

Comment: This version has been release here: https://pypi.org/project/recurrent/